# \Driver\WudfRd failed to load for the device ROOT\WPD\0000

Tags: audio, drivers, windows-8.1, multiple-monitors

After moving all of my monitors to one of my GPUs, so that I can use the SLI feature, I keep seeing this:

1. Primary monitor goes black, and the sound stops working (hear the repeating audio of whatever was last said).
2. Other monitors then flash black to normal and so on for a few moments, then completely go black.
3. The last two steps all take about 10 seconds.  If I leave it alone, it comes  back to normal after about an entire minute.  Everything appears to be fine, and no immediate errors are given.

Nothing else has changed, and the temperatures are fine.

I looked in my event viewer, and I receive the following errors and warnings (in order):

1. The UMDF reflector was unable to complete startup because the WUDFPf service was not found.  This service may be started later during boot, at which point Windows will attempt to start the device again.
2. The driver \Driver\WudfRd failed to load for the device ROOT\WPD\0000.
3. Performance power management features on processor 0 in group 0 are disabled due to a firmware problem. Check with the computer manufacturer for updated firmware.  (processer 0 goes from 0 to 7, so 8 errors, all the same, just with an increased processor number)
4. Crash dump initialization failed!

This has occurred about 10 times, and I have received the same order of errors every time.

Comment: download and run [slimDrivers](http://slimdrivers.en.softonic.com/) and make sure your drivers are correct/up to date

Comment: @gudthing went ahead and did that.  Will see if there is any change.  Thanks.

Comment: not sure what to suggest, maybe try [reading this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/the-umdf-reflector-was-unable-to-complete-startup/1f00e407-3c6f-4308-99e3-289d77b90e7d) and try some of their solutions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out it was my graphics card having issues as I suspected.  Turns out that I needed to change my power settings in the Nvidia Control panel to favor performance.

Comment: Where have you changed that?

Comment: @stefan go to nvidia control panel -> 3D Settings -> Manage 3D settings -> Power management mode. Make sure it is set to HIGH PERFORMANCE, not Adaptive

Comment: Thx for your response but after I lost one entire working week I felt the decision to sell my Graphic card ^^
Problem occurred after I plugged in my new Dell UltraSharp U3415W. Graphic card was Gainward GTX 770 4gb.
In modern days a NO-Go for me